# App design question for multiple "data" connections

Tags: android

I am working on developing an application that requires me to
establish multiple client-server based connections. Connection can be
of two types where the Android device can be a server or a client. I
can have up to 6 - 8 connections. Once the connections are set-up they
need to be running in the background and are not typically affected by
UI actions.

Since each connection can be blocking, I am wondering what is a good
away to design this app. Should I have two services for handling the
server and client connections? Each service could have a "connection
manager" that can spawn new threads when necessary. Or does creating
two services even help? I presume spawning new processed would not be
good as they will be expensive. Is this correct?

I would appreciate any suggestions. Also, if this use case is not
typical please let me know if you need more information to make any
recommendation.

Thanks,
-Ray

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement a service with that manage a thread pool
I made something similar if you want I can give you a hand... 
Luigi